# Mysql subquery laravel 8.0

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-8

I am trying to filter the results of my query to get only the results with RANK <=5;
I have this Laravel statement

```
      $data = DB::table('n2ns')->select('first_name', 'last_name','name_abb_mappings.team', 'name_abb_mappings.cc','project_id',
          DB::raw('projects.request_name as project_name'),DB::raw('projects.request_from as end_date'),
          DB::raw('projects.request_to as start_date'), DB::raw('sum(hit) as points'),
          DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(concat(word, '->'), concat(hit, ' ') separator ' ' ) as word"),
          DB::raw("row_number() OVER (partition by project_id order by  sum(hit) desc) AS 'RANK'"))
          ->join('projects','n2ns.project_id','projects.request_id')
          ->leftJoin('name_abb_mappings','n2ns.abbreviation','name_abb_mappings.id')
          ->groupBy('abbreviation','project_id')
          //->having('RANK','<=','5')
          ->get();
```

Notice the commented `having` clause.

This statement produces me this sql query:

```
 select `first_name`, `last_name`, `name_abb_mappings`.`team`,
 `name_abb_mappings`.`cc`, `project_id`,
 projects.request_name as project_name, 
 projects.request_from as end_date, projects.request_to as start_date,
 sum(hit) as points, GROUP_CONCAT(concat(word, '->'), concat(hit, ' ') separator ' ' ) as word, row_number() OVER (partition by project_id order by  sum(hit) desc) AS 'RANK' 
 from `n2ns` inner join `projects` on `n2ns`.`project_id` = `projects`.`request_id` 
 left join `name_abb_mappings` on `n2ns`.`abbreviation` = `name_abb_mappings`.`id` 
 group by `abbreviation`, `project_id`
```

When i use the `having` clause it throws me this error:

> You cannot use the alias 'RANK' of an expression containing a window function in this context

So the solution is simply to put the whole query in a subquery and filter like:

```
    select * from (query) as data
where data.RANK <=5;
```

But how can i do that in laravel? I tried diffrent ways but none is working. Or better said i am not getting them right. Can someone give me an advice? Appreciate your help.

Comment: i think `AS 'RANK'` should be `AS RANK` without the qoutes

Comment: It throws me an syntax error

Comment: No more ideas? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be not the best solution but it solved my problem.

It's possible to write complete raw queries without using the in build functions of query builder. So i did it like this.

```
    $data=DB::select(DB::raw('select* from(select
 `first_name`, `last_name`, `name_abb_mappings`.`team`,
 `name_abb_mappings`.`cc`, `project_id`, projects.request_name as project_name,
 projects.request_from as end_date, projects.request_to as start_date, sum(hit) as points,
 GROUP_CONCAT(concat(word, "->"), concat(hit, " ") separator " " ) as "word",
 row_number() OVER (partition by project_id order by  sum(hit) desc) AS "RANK"
 from n2ns inner join projects on `n2ns`.`project_id` = `projects`.`request_id`
 left join `name_abb_mappings` on `n2ns`.`abbreviation` = `name_abb_mappings`.`id`
 group by `abbreviation`, `project_id`
 order by projects.request_name) as d
 where d.RANK <= 5'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`RANK` is a build-in function in MySQL, so you are probably colliding with it.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank

Comment: i renamed it to `data` same error `General error: 3594 You cannot use the alias 'data' of an expression containing a window function in this contex`

Comment: try `my-rank` without quotes

Comment: when i remove the quotes it throws me an syntanx error. And when i add them and put 'my-rank' it gives me again the same error. I think this is my problem: https://learnsql.com/blog/window-functions-not-allowed-in-where/ and here is an example to solve the problem https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-select-top-3-highest-count-for-each-category-in-laravel. The solution given there like `DB::query(DB::raw($sql));` is not working for me, because the `query` function doesnt exist in my laravel version. So still no clue how to manage my query to get my desired results. :(

Comment: i see, looks like that is the problem, but you are not using it in `having` only after select

Comment: what do you mean? Actually i am using it in `having`. Here its commented out, but when i test it i uncomment it of course. Hope i am getting you right. I am desperate about this, Did not think its so difficult.